# Only allow Stripe Purchases on certain model parameters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Rails newbie here, working with Stripe's API. I have a model in my rails app called pieces. Each piece has an integer called status. I only want people to be able to purchase the piece if the piece has a status of 1. In my current code, I have hid the buy button on the pieces unless the piece of the status is 1. This works most of the time, but, if two people view the piece at the same time, then they can both buy them. This is because the status of the piece on the other page does not update until the page is reloaded.

My request: I want to find a way to check that the piece's status is 1, right before someone buys it. If it is not 1, I want there to be a rails flash message saying that the piece has already been bought. This should prevent the user from being charged and prevent a `charge` from being created.

Here is my charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def create

    piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => piece.total_price_in_cents,
      :description => piece.title,
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

    purchase = Purchase.create(
        customer_email: params[:stripeEmail],

        total_transaction: piece.total_price,
        stripe_fee: piece.stripe_fee,
        taxes: piece.taxes,
        artist_cut: piece.artist_cut,
        charity_cut: piece.charity_cut,
        our_cut: piece.our_cut,

        currency: charge.currency,
        card: params[:stripeToken],
        description: charge.description, 
        customer_id: customer.id,
        piece_id: piece.id, 

        customer_name: params[:stripeShippingName],
        customer_address_line_1: params[:stripeShippingAddressLine1],
        customer_city: params[:stripeShippingAddressCity],
        customer_state: params[:stripeShippingAddressState],
        customer_zip_code: params[:stripeShippingAddressZip],
        customer_country: params[:stripeShippingAddressCountry],

        seller_name: piece.user.name,
        seller_email: piece.user.email,
        seller_address_line_1: piece.user.address_line_1,
        seller_address_line_2: piece.user.address_line_2,
        seller_city: piece.user.city,
        seller_state: piece.user.state,
        seller_zip_code: piece.user.zip_code

    )

    purchase.ship_by = purchase.created_at + 7.days
    purchase.arrive_by = purchase.created_at + 21.days
    purchase.save!

    piece.status = 3
    piece.save!
    redirect_to pieces_path, notice: "Thanks for buying #{piece.title} for $#{'%.2f' % piece.total_price}. You should get an email shortly."

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end

  end
```

And here is my show page for the pieces, which has the stripe buy button on it:

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">

      <!-- Stripe Form -->
      <% if current_user != @piece.user && @piece.status == 1 %>
         <%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargeForm' do %>
              <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>


              <button id="btn-buy-show" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Buy for $<%= number_with_precision(@piece.total_price, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',')%></button>
              <script>
              var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
                shippingAddress: true,
                token: function(token, arg) {
                  document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
                  document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
                  document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
                }
              });
               document.getElementById('btn-buy-show').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                handler.open({
                  name: 'Metallic Palette',
                  description: '<%= @piece.title %> ($<%= number_with_precision(@piece.total_price, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',')%>)',
                  amount: document.getElementById("amount").value
              });
              e.preventDefault();
             })
            </script>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <% if @piece.status == 3 %>
        <p>This piece has already been bought.
          <% if current_user == @piece.user || admin_user_signed_in? %>
            <%= render 'pieces/purchase_details' %>
          <% end %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check it :)

```
def create
  piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])

  if piece.status != 1
    flash[:error] = 'Piece is not available :('
    return redirect_to peaces_path # or whatever
  end

  ...
end
```

However, few suggests for you:
1) Don't use numbers in your code. Make constants (like `Piece::AVAILABLE`) and methods (`piece.available?`) or use `enum`. You will have lots of problems in future, if you will just use your numbers

2) Extract form object - you don't want to have so large methods in your controller. If you extract it to separate service - it will be much more testable, predictable and updatable.

3) Extract `Piece.find` and piece status check into before_filters.